# Como automatizar um deploy no Apache?

Tags: apache, deploy, automatização

Tenho alguns sistemas baseados em Django que frequentemente precisam ser implantados (*deployed*) em servidores diferentes. Isso envolve entre outras coisas instalar todas as dependências, baixar os arquivos do projeto, colocá-los numa pasta padronizada, etc, tudo isso podendo ser feito através de um simples script.

Entretanto, uma parte desse processo eu sempre tenho feito manualmente, já que não conheço uma boa maneira de automatizar/semi-automatizar:

1. Fazer a configuração básica do Apache (se for a primeira instalação dele também);
2. Criar um *virtual host* para minha aplicação; em geral é apenas um arquivo mais ou menos com esse formato:

   ```
   <VirtualHost X.X.X.X:443>
       SSLEngine On
       ServerName <<nome do servidor>>
       ServerAlias <<nome alternativo>>
       ServerAdmin <<e-mail do administrador>>

       DocumentRoot /opt/<<pasta da aplicação>>
       Alias /media/ /opt/<<pasta da aplicação>>/media/
       Alias /static/ /opt/<<pasta da aplicação>>/static/

       WSGIDaemonProcess <<processo wsgi>> user=<<usuario>> group=<<grupo>> threads=1
       WSGIProcessGroup <<grupo wsgi>>
       WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/<<pasta da aplicação>>/aplicacao.wsgi
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   a ser colocado no `sites-available` com link no `sites-enabled`. Esse é o mais fácil: em último caso, posso gerar o arquivo dados os parâmetros desejados. Mas se tiver um jeito mais simples, melhor.

Existem ferramentas - do próprio Apache ou de terceiros (de preferência *open-source*) - para simplificar essa configuração, sem demandar editar o `httpd.conf` e seus vários arquivos referenciados? Ou, caso a resposta seja não, qual o melhor meio de editar programaticamente esses arquivos? Ao contrário de formatos populares como XML, JSON e YAML, não conheço nenhum leitor/escritor para o formato deles.

P.S. Estou assumindo um ambiente Linux/Unix, e a linguagem de programação não importa (mas se houver uma solução em Python, tanto melhor).

Comment: Vou fazer um jabá da empresa de um amigo meu que trabalha apenas com configuração: https://configr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar todo o servidor utilizando o [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org).

> Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for
>   streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems
>   administration tasks.

Com ele é possível criar um arquivo (fabfile.py) dentro do seu projeto Django, e neste arquivo colocar os comandos para se conectar ao servidor via SSH e realizar **todas** as configurações necessárias.

Neste caso do Apache, seria algo como:

```
# -*- encoding:utf-8 -*-
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.colors import green, red, yellow

env.host_string = 'ip do seu servidor'
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.key_filename = ''

def configurar_servidor():
    ...
    print(green(u'Instalando apache...'))
    ...
    print(green(u'Configurando...'))
    run('sudo cp /home/ubuntu/seuprojeto/config/apache/arquivo diretoriodoapache/sites-available/arquivo')
    ...
```

Coloquei apenas uma ideia, após instalar o Fabric no ambiente virtual do seu projeto, localmente você entraria com o comando para executar as tarefas desse arquivo. Com ele é possível configurar tudo do zero, desde a criação de instâncias na Amazon, até download do seu projeto do git, instalação do virtualenv, banco de dados e etc.